# Unable to install TensorFlow using apt on Ubuntu 18.04 - unmet dependencies on nvidia-driver-418

Tags: tensorflow, linux-device-driver, nvidia

I am following [these instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#ubuntu_1804_cuda_10) to install TensorFlow.

when I try to run the command `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends nvidia-driver-418`, I get the error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-driver-418 : Depends: nvidia-driver-430 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am no Linux expert, so the statement that driver 418 depends on driver 430 is very confusing to me.

Comment: There's a newer version of the 10.0 toolkit; try cuda-repo-ubuntu1804_10.1.168-1_amd64.deb instead of cuda-repo-ubuntu1804_10.0.130-1_amd64.deb

Comment: Well this is embarrassing: all that was needed was `sudo apt upgrade`. Apparently the earlier steps resulted in stuff that needed to be upgraded. Possibly related @Michael comment.

Answer (score 0):

Run:  `sudo apt-get -f install` to fix broken packages. Then `sudo apt update`. After that, follow the tutorial. Finally:

```
pip3 install tensorflow-gpu
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove installed nvidia-driver.

Run:

```
apt remove nvidia-driver-*
```

Then retry:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends nvidia-driver-418
```